# How to add one red pixel to the screen

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using Cocos2d-iphone and want to add one red pixel to the screen.
I tried creating an CCSprite but the size should only be one pixel.

I don't want to create an image file.

How to realize it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cocos2d: How do I generate a texture, sprite, or image from a 2D array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14927737/cocos2d-how-do-i-generate-a-texture-sprite-or-image-from-a-2d-array)

Comment: No, that is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift - almost the same as Viktor's answer - but instead of creating 1 `CCDrawNode` object per pixel, it will draw in the same `CCDrawNode` object everytime the `drawDot` got called.

create _drawNode member variable

```
var _drawNode : CCDrawNode!
```

initiate the CCDrawNode object

```
_drawNode = CCDrawNode()
self.addChild(_drawNode) // add it to the node you are currently in

// draw the dot, can be recalled anywhere in this class
let touchLocation = ccp(10,10)
_drawNode.drawDot(touchLocation, radius: 1, color: CColor.blackColor())
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved it, there is a method in the CCDrawNode class, with which you can paint a dot:

```
    CCDrawNode *oneRedPixelA = [[CCDrawNode alloc] init];
    CGPoint positionA = CGPointMake(aLabel.contentSize.width * aLabel.anchorPoint.x, aLabel.contentSize.height * aLabel.anchorPoint.y);
    [oneRedPixelA drawDot:positionA radius:3.0f color:ccc4f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f)];
    [aLabel addChild:oneRedPixelA z:500];
```